# Chrome PepperFlash takes very high CPU usage

Tags: flash, google-chrome, cpu

I have a SWF where there is a frame showing a button with a changing glow filter that will be re-calculated every frame.

The problem here is, while running this SWF in chrome with pepperflash plugin, the CPU usage increases to approximately 50%. If I run the same SWF in Firefox, it only costs around 10% CPU usage.

However, when I switch from pepperflash to flash debug player in chrome, the CPU usage drops to around 20%.

How can I solve this problem? I want ordinary users who use chrome with pepperflash plugin to have a better experience, at least decrease the CPU usage by half. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but seems I couldn't find an answer there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under certain conditions, the PepperFlash plugin is a CPU hog. Since AFAIK there is no other Flash plugin option other than the Debug Flash Player you mentioned, the only workaround I've found to avoid skipped frames/rough playback/high CPU usage is to enable the *Disable hardware-accelerated video decode.* flag in chrome://flags (click on the *Enable* link. The image below shows the switch enabled).

[image]

This has dropped usage to about half what it was before, just as you desired.

**Note 1**: I should note that my laptop has an integrated (non dedicated) GPU, and 
rendering via software acceleration seems to work better in my case.

**Note 2**: I have not tested how this impacts non flash and HTML 5 video rendering. The switch is for disabling hardware acceleration for *all* video decoding. AFAIK you cannot disable hardware acceleration only for Flash video - there is no such switch. Therefore, chrome://gpu still shows that Flash is still hardware accelerated but it seems the global setting takes precedence:

[image]